# LT Spice simulation error: 'Time step too small'

Tags: power-supply, power, control, flyback, ac-dc

Could someone get this up and running? Tried all the possibilities but it does not seem to work still.

Here I am just trying to simulate the linked circuit here ..  [PMP7763 design reference](https://www.ti.com/tool/PMP7763)
[image]

Comment: You're missing grounding on the secondary side. What are those "all the possibilities" that you tried?

Comment: According to my experience, one ground point per simulation is good enough. The secondary side not necessarily have any ground reference.

Comment: Undefined voltages tend to be one of the causes of unpredictable simulation behaviour like convergence or timestep errors. If you don't want a ground connection on the secondary side, at least connect a 1Gigohm resistor from secondary to GND.

Comment: It's a simulation; not real life - help the sim by grounding the secondary.

Comment: Grounding on the secondary side did not help.

Comment: Can you list everything else you have tried?  For example, have you tried setting `.options cshunt` to a non-zero value?  Also, you can copy/paste the `.asc` file's text into a code block in your question so others can try tinkering around to try to get it to work.